# Android studio Room database migration error - table scrambled

Tags: android-studio, android-room

I am working on my first migration of a Room database version. For this i have choosen the "manual" migration. In my table i added 1 field/column at the end and an index.
Then in my migration function i added this

```
private val migration2To3: Migration = object: Migration(2,3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

            Log.i("database", "migration from $startVersion to $endVersion started")

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'gps' ADD COLUMN 'isTrack' BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false")
            Log.i("database", "TABLE gps altered. 1 new column added")

            database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_gps_tripId` ON `gps` (`tripId`)")
            Log.i("database", "TABLE gps index on 'tripId' added")

            Log.i("database", "migration from $startVersion to $endVersion ended")
        }
 }
```

Now i see the logging lines which let me to believe al was ok but a second later my app crashes with this message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
> Process: com.example.tripmemory, PID: 15190
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
> at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0(RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:74)
> at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.$r8$lambda$PhMGW5zFk4QWazERd2lfEeLZqW0(Unknown Source:0)
> at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: gps(com.example.tripmemory.objects.GPSDataObject).
> **Expected**:
> TableInfo{name='gps', columns={altitude=Column{name='altitude', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isTrack=Column{name='isTrack', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, datetime=Column{name='datetime', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, icon=Column{name='icon', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, tripId=Column{name='tripId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, memoryId=Column{name='memoryId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='memory', onDelete='CASCADE +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[memoryId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='trip', onDelete='CASCADE +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[tripId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_gps_memoryId', unique=false, columns=[memoryId], orders=[ASC]'}, Index{name='index_gps_tripId', unique=false, columns=[tripId], orders=[ASC]'}]}
> **Found**:
> E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='gps', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='undefined'}, tripId=Column{name='tripId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, memoryId=Column{name='memoryId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, longitude=Column{name='longitude', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, latitude=Column{name='latitude', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, altitude=Column{name='altitude', type='REAL', affinity='4', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, datetime=Column{name='datetime', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, icon=Column{name='icon', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'}, isTrack=Column{name='isTrack', type='BOOLEAN', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='false'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='memory', onDelete='CASCADE +', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[memoryId], referenceColumnNames=[id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_gps_tripId', unique=false, columns=[tripId], orders=[ASC]'}, Index{name='index_gps_memoryId', unique=false, columns=[memoryId], orders=[ASC]'}]}
> at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.kt:94)
> at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:252)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:416)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
> at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableOrReadableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:231)
> at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.innerGetDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:189)
> at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:151)
> at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:104)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:629)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.kt:448)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.kt:477)
> at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.kt:75)
> at com.example.tripmemory.dataabase.TripMemoryDao_Impl$23.call(TripMemoryDao_Impl.java:493)
> at com.example.tripmemory.dataabase.TripMemoryDao_Impl$23.call(TripMemoryDao_Impl.java:490)
> at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0(RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:72)
> ... 5 more

What is strange is column order of the expected table is completly scrambled. I did not change  anything in the order of the fields. when i look at the schema export of the two version (before and after) it also there has the same field order in both version just with the new extra field at the end in the newest version.
So what am i doing wrong. Only thing i can think of to fix it is to use "fallbackToDestructiveMigration" which is an option for now as the app is not live but when it is that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is strange is column order of the expected table is completly scrambled.

The order of the columns is irrelevant. Your issue is the use of the column type BOOLEAN and also the use of a DEFAULT value.

The type should instead be **INTEGER**.

- Room only supports column types that are one of:-

  - INTEGER, REAL, TEXT or BLOB

So you want to use

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'gps' ADD COLUMN 'isTrack' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT false")
```

**However**, you then have the issue that if the NOT NULL constraint is used, you MUST have a default value when using the ADD COLUMN. To indicate to Room that you are using a DEFAULT value then you need to use `defaultValue` parameter of the `@ColumnInfo` annotation for the member variable/field specifying `false` as the value.

The issues can be seen by looking at the **isTrack** column in the expected and found. The result showing a difference in the affinity, type and default value. As per:-

```
isTrack=Column{name='isTrack', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='undefined'},

isTrack=Column{name='isTrack', type='BOOLEAN', affinity='1', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='false'
```

Comment: Thank you MikeT. I am on holiday now so not able to implement you answer but i do havw a followup question. Becauae in the entity class i can define types like boolean. Does room/studio automaticly translate this into column types you mentioned? And is there some place where i can see that a boolean in studio is translated to integer? Just so that in the furure i can do it correctly.

Comment: @Michel, yes ( to auto translate) and yes (to place). If you successfully compile the project with the Entities in the entities parameter of the `@Database` and then  from the Android View look at the generated java, there will be a class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl**, the **createAllTables** method has the SQL for creating the tables and thus the resultant types etc of how Room interprets the entities. i.e. what Room expects.